# Making keyboard shortcut, but it does not do anything

Tags: python, python-3.x, shortcut, pyautogui, python-keyboard

I am trying to make a shortcut to open google when I do the function normal it works but when I try to do it in a shortcut it doesn't work.

```
import pyautogui as pg
import keyboard
hotkey1 = "ctrl+alt+w"

def google():
    pg.hotkey("win")
    pg.typewrite("google\n", 0.05)

while True:
    if keyboard.is_pressed(hotkey1):   
        google()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You only need a pause until pg can take over. It so happens that when you press the hotkey combo, you might accidentally hit some other keys and therefore it doesn't work as intended. This should give it enough time for the key to be depressed before the automatic process starts.

```
import time
def google():
    time.sleep(0.25)
    pg.hotkey("win")
    pg.typewrite("google\n", 0.05)
```